# Viewing MAMP Pro site on iPad

Tags: mamp

I've just started using the paid version of MAMP, MAMP Pro, and I'm having some trouble accessing my site via my iPad/iPhone.

I've got my MAMP server set up with the default ports (80, 3306) and am trying to visit the site on my iPad via: `10.0.1.2:80/project-name`.

But no dice, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`xip.io`](http://xip.io/) address.

Select your host in MAMP PRO (`client.dev` in this example), go to the Advanced tab and put this in the Customized General Settings: `ServerAlias client.*.xip.io`

Set WP URLs to `http://client.YOUR-LOCALHOST-IP-ADDRESS.xip.io`.

For development, it's better to set a static IP DHCP address in your system preferences.

Restart everything, run!

I've [answered the same](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98419/12615) a bit more in-depth in WordPress Answers.

Comment: @ATLChris, glad to hear that SO's mission is accomplished: *"help future users"*, as the original poster didn't provide any feedback ;)