# Tools to test mobile version of site

Tags: html, css

Are there any tools that can show me how my site will look on mobile if it hasn't yet been hosted? All the ones I've found require the site to already be online.

Comment: What's your setup? Mac? Linux? Windows?

Comment: Without details is pretty impossible to answer clearly to your question. Anyway, if you're dealing with HTML files, open them in a browser and, if you're working with a responsive design, just resize the browser window and you'll see the differences.

Comment: Sorry I'm on a mac. Stupidly, it hadn't even occurred to me to just re-size the window. Is that really the best way to do it, though? I'm fairly new to coding so I apologise for the noobish questions.

Comment: [Viewing MAMP Pro Site on iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15437962/1287812)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [Responsinator.com](http://www.responsinator.com/) but there are a billion other similar websites.  It basically just iframes in your page with a ton of different device sizes.

The site does not have to be hosted online, this works with locally hosted sites as well (e.g. on localhost with WAMP/MAMP).

Note that free sites like this don't generally do any browser testing, just viewport size... most of the options that actually use VMs to simulate different device browsers are paid/premium services, and those need to be hosted online somewhere so their testing servers can access it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, I appreciate it! I'm clearly just being an idiot but whenever I enter the path to my index.html it just comes up with "server not found". I assume this is because I'm not entering the path correctly but it displays my page when I enter it like that in my browser.

Comment: That's weird.  Try using WAMP (if you're on windows) or MAMP (Mac) to run apache locally, which will create hostnames (e.g. `localhost/yoursite`) and simulate a real webserver.  I'm not sure why it wouldn't work with a direct path but it works for me on sites on localhost.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I'd upvote if I had the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

1. http://www.browserstack.com/ - Free 30 min. version
2. http://mobiletest.me/
3. http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/10/8-popular-online-apps-to-test-the-mobile-version-of-your-site/ Collection of resourses for testing.

Comment: Thank you, number 3 has a bunch of tools that look really useful.