# Viewing Wordpress Sites Stored On LocalHost From Another Device

Tags: wordpress, mobile, browser, local, host

Ok so I don't know if this question is suitable for StackOverflow or not so I apologize if it's not.  Here is the problem, I develop my wordpress themes on my localhost 'localhost/~jamiemcardle/wordpress' and thats fine.  I can go to my iPhone and type in '192.168.0.8/~jamiemcardle/website' or whatever the address number is to access a website stored in that folder.  But if I type '192.168.0.8/~jamiemcardle/Wordpress' it loads the wordpress site without any styling.  Why?  How can I fix this?  Also Safari and Chrome do this on iPhone but all browsers are ok on Macbook.

Thanks

Comment: I use [xip.io](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15437962/1287812) for that

Answer (score 0):

Easiest fix would be to change the site URL in the WP options to the IP address (so replace localhost with your I.P).

The lack of styling is due to the fact that the site is looking for "localhost/wp-content/themes/theme-name/style.css" but is obviously unable to find it due to the fact that that's NOT the address you're visiting.

Always use the IP instead of localhost to avoid problems of this nature.

Comment: I am using the IP address on mobile tho :/

Comment: Aye, but the site is using "localhost", which is independant for each device - so when you visit on your mobile, it's trying to find the "localhost" on your phone, which obviously doesn't exist. Setting the actual site address as the IP will resolve the issue, irrelevant of what device you view it on, and obviously it can still be viewed on the host computer via the IP